# Where should the instance object of a class put into in Python

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

I have an main.py which look like:

```
from redisUtil import redisProducer

def foo():
    redis_producer.get_data()
    ...

def main():
    while True:
        if # certain condition
            foo()
            ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where should I create an instance object of a class like this?

```
redis_producer = redisProducer()
```

Should it be an parameter of `main()`, under `if __name__ == "__main__"` or somewhere else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where do you need to use ```redis_producer```?  It looks like only in ```foo()```.  Do you need it elsewhere?

Comment: I want to know how to deal with both cases, 1. only `foo()` in main.py, 2. more than one function need in main.py, thanks! @ewokx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it globally (means anywhere) in your main.py file you can instantiate out of functions and use it anywhere in your functions like this:

```
from redisUtil import redisProducer

redis_producer = redisProducer()
def foo():
    redis_producer.get_data()
    ...

def main():
    foo()
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but if you want to use it only in a single function you can just instantiate within the specific function like this:

```
 from redisUtil import redisProducer
    
    
    def foo():
        redis_producer = redisProducer()
        redis_producer.get_data()
        ...
    
    def main():
        foo()
        ...
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: What if I will call `foo()` multiple times, should I create an object instance in `foo()` everytime?

Comment: calling foo() multiple times has no problem with redis_producer instance because already created within the function or outside the function, so you can just use it multiple times whenever you call foo() function

Comment: So If I call `foo()` multiple times and create the instance inside the function, will it be created every single time I call `foo()`(kinda redundant), is it better create it in global if I need to use `redis_producer,get_data()` for multiple times?

Comment: try to use it as global

Comment: May I ask global means under `if __name__ == "__main__":` or under `import`?